# Facebook Plugins wont work with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, plugins

I have a blog page that uses ajax to call different article from PHP files once the relevant link is clicked. The problem is that when the PHP loads the Facebook plug-ins don't work. If I open the PHP files using the URL directly in the address bar on the browser then they work fine. I am including links to my page so that you can see it in action. If you replace blog.html with blog1.php you will see what I mean. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks. http://www.tagwebsites.com.au/blog.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery - Facebook like button with asyncronous script tag dynamic loaded not initialized twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501001/jquery-facebook-like-button-with-asyncronous-script-tag-dynamic-loaded-not-ini)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort this out with the help of Facebook. The issue was as simple as adding the BFML tag to the html tag at the top of each page. It works great now. Thank you to everyone that sent messages through. I really appreciate your help.